# Review First post goto Suggested edit without any come back option

Tags: discussion, feature-request

While reviewing [First Post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts) i have look one weird things. I am reviewing following post given in  below image.

[image]

In this post, question and description is proper but, need only edit the post. Any other person having reputation below 2000 edited that post and currently it is in review queue.

Now, i click on edit link to check all edited things are proper or not.

So, it will move me to suggested edit review screen. As i have attached below screen.

[image]

Now, i review it and click on anything like Approve/ Improve Edit Or any one.
Here if i improve edit then it will continue to review suggested edit. Now, i never come back to review first post as i started to review.

Now, if i want to review First post i need to start from first.

Don't know it is bug or feature request. But, i post it as feature request as there is no any other option to come back to first post is given.

**Edit:**

I got one suggestion in comment that. Right click and open in new tab.

But, When i review that suggested edit and come back to first posts. `I'm Done` button not enable.

What should i do in that situation if all other things are ok. `NO Action Needed` is right option even though i have audit the edit suggested?

It make boring to review then after if required lots of click and page movement loading.

Comment: You can review pending suggested edits on a post even if you are reviewing  the post itself on another queue.

Comment: @Braiam But, i can not come back to first post after review that suggested edit.

Comment: @ketan Right click on "edit(1)" to open the link in a new tab/window.

Comment: Just press "Back" in the browser two times. Worked for me so far ;-)

Comment: Why should user need to click lots for review? It should be simple