# Editing a post in First Posts Review queue changes the queue to suggested edits review

Tags: feature-request, bug, review-queues

I'm trying to review posts that have piled up in the Review [First Posts queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/17334778). Some of these posts already have edits suggested, and when I want to review those edits (to improve or approve them), my queue automagically changes to [Suggested Edits queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17334753).

From which point, I now have to come back manually to the queue I was reviewing earlier.

So the suggestion is to alter the flow and have an improve edit button within the first posts queue, so that the user stays within the original queue. (The same is true for any other review queue if they have a similar behavior of change of queue).

Comment: shouldn't your title be something like "reviewing an edit while reviewing first Posts..." since editing itself won't Change the Queue?

Comment: This odd behavior has been [asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276278/review-queue-bait-and-switch) [about](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316560/review-first-post-goto-suggested-edit-without-any-come-back-option) [before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302507/clicking-edit1-took-me-away-from-the-first-post-review-queue). It still hasn't been fixed. And it confuses me every time.